# Tile Map Usage Much CPU With OpenGL and SDL

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, cpu-usage, tile

I been working in a method to draw a map based on tiles with OpenGL and SDL. And I finally coded but when I execute the basic program where it draw a tile map of 25x16, and I check the use of CPU, it says that consume 25% but without drawing the map consume by much 1% of CPU.

So exists another method to draw the map or why is the use of CPU so high.

This is the code for drawing the map.

```
void CMapManager::drawMap(Map *map)
{
    vector<ImagePtr> tempImages = CGameApplication::getInstance()->getGameApp()->getImages();
    GLuint texture = tempImages.at(1)->getTexture();

    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );
    glBegin( GL_QUADS );

        for (int i = 0; i < map->getHeight(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < map->getWidth(); j++)
            {
                ImagePtr imgDraw = tempImages.at(map->getMapTiles()[i][j]->getTypeTile());

                glTexCoord2i( 0, 0 );
                glVertex3f( imgDraw->getPosX() + (imgDraw->getWidth()*j), imgDraw->getPosY() + (imgDraw->getHeight()*i), 0.f );

                //Bottom-left vertex (corner)
                glTexCoord2i( 1, 0 );
                glVertex3f( imgDraw->getOffsetX() + (imgDraw->getWidth()*j), imgDraw->getPosY() + (imgDraw->getHeight()*i), 0.f );

                //Bottom-right vertex (corner)
                glTexCoord2i( 1, 1 );
                glVertex3f( imgDraw->getOffsetX() + (imgDraw->getWidth()*j), imgDraw->getOffsetY() + (imgDraw->getHeight()*i), 0.f );

                //Top-right vertex (corner)
                glTexCoord2i( 0, 1 );
                glVertex3f( imgDraw->getPosX() + (imgDraw->getWidth()*j),  imgDraw->getOffsetY() + (imgDraw->getHeight()*i), 0.f );
            }
        }       

    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_BLEND);

}
```

And in this method I call the function:

```
void CGameApplication::renderApplication()
{       
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT ); 
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    vector<ImagePtr> tempImages = GApp->getImages();
    vector<ImagePtr>::iterator iterImage;

    for (iterImage = tempImages.begin(); iterImage != tempImages.end(); ++iterImage)
    {
        CImageM->drawSprites( (*iterImage)->getTexture(), (*iterImage)->getPosX(), (*iterImage)->getPosY(), 
                            (*iterImage)->getOffsetX(), (*iterImage)->getOffsetY() );
    }

    vector<TextPtr> tempTexts = GApp->getTexts();
    vector<TextPtr>::iterator iterText;

    for (iterText = tempTexts.begin(); iterText != tempTexts.end(); ++iterText)
    {
        CTextM->drawFonts( (*iterText) );
    }

    CMapM->drawMap(GApp->getCurrentMap());

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

}
```

I already set a Timer that after this function:

```
    GameApplication->getCKeyboardHandler()->inputLogic();
    GameApplication->renderApplication();

    SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();

    GameApplication->getGameApp()->getTimer()->delay();
```

And the delay function is:

```
void Timer::delay()
{
    if( this->getTicks() < 1000 / FRAMES_PER_SECOND )
    {
        SDL_Delay( ( 1000 / FRAMES_PER_SECOND ) - this->getTicks() );
    }
}
```

The const FRAMES_PER_SECOND it's 5 in this moment.

And the function for convert image to GL texture is:

```
GLuint CImageManager::imageToGLTexture(std::string name)
{
    GLuint texture;     
    SDL_Surface *surface;   
    GLenum texture_format;
    GLint  nOfColors;

    if ( (surface = IMG_Load(name.c_str())) ) { 

        // Check that the image's width is a power of 2
        if ( (surface->w & (surface->w - 1)) != 0 ) {
            printf("warning: image.bmp's width is not a power of 2\n");
        }

        // Also check if the height is a power of 2
        if ( (surface->h & (surface->h - 1)) != 0 ) {
            printf("warning: image.bmp's height is not a power of 2\n");
        }

        // get the number of channels in the SDL surface
        nOfColors = surface->format->BytesPerPixel;
        if (nOfColors == 4)     // contains an alpha channel
        {
            if (surface->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff)
                    texture_format = GL_RGBA;
            else
                    texture_format = GL_BGRA_EXT;
        } 

        else if (nOfColors == 3)     // no alpha channel
        {
            if (surface->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff)
                    texture_format = GL_RGB;
            else
                    texture_format = GL_BGR_EXT;
        } 

        else {
            printf("warning: the image is not truecolor..  this will probably break\n");
            // this error should not go unhandled
        }

        SDL_SetAlpha(surface, 0, 0);

        // Have OpenGL generate a texture object handle for us
        glGenTextures( 1, &texture );

        // Bind the texture object
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );

        // Set the texture's stretching properties
        glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
        glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );

        // Edit the texture object's image data using the information SDL_Surface gives us
        glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, nOfColors, surface->w, surface->h, 0,
                              texture_format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surface->pixels );
    } 

    else {
        printf("SDL could not load the image: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        exit(1);
    }    

    if ( surface ) { 
        SDL_FreeSurface( surface );
    }

    return texture;
}
```

Thanks before hand for the help.

Comment: That's not so bad ... try running some other 3d applications and look at the CPU usage during render time.

Comment: I run some basic 3D applications, and use 20% CPU, 15% CPU, max 30% CPU, but that's why I' worried my application it's 2D and it's not finished yet, what it means that it will use a bit more of CPU. So that it's normal?

Comment: Premature optimization is the devil. Design, code, test, then profile to determine what areas of your code can be optimized when your project is complete.

Comment: Thanks I will have that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all, avoid state changes. Combine all your tiles into one texture and render using only one `glBegin`/`glEnd` block.

If you don't want to make many changes try [display lists](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_displaylist.html). OpenGL will be able to optimize your calls but there is no guarantee it will run much faster.

If your map doesn't change a lot use VBOs. It's the fastest way.

Comment: But if I combine all the tiles in one texture, I will have to regenerate that texture in every loop because some of the tiles have to change. For example, if the main character destroy a element of the map or something like that, this tile it's not going to draw anymore, so combine all the tiles in one texture it will cost a bit much?? or am I wrong?......Unfortunately the map changes almost constantly so VBO's or display lists doesn't help me much. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @oscar.rpr: I meant something like [this](http://www.swingswingsubmarine.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/Woodland_Tileset.png). All images are on single texture so you don't have to call `glBindTexture`. Instead use `glTexCoord2i` to select the correct part of the image.

Comment: If only the textures are changing, the VBOs need not change with them, unless you are updating UVs with the textures.  UV updates will in general be the fastest way to animate stuff in my experience. Also, if you aren't changing every map's VBO every tic, they will still probably be faster.  You should investigate it.

Comment: @oscar He means creating a single texture of all tiles then indexing into this texture that you keep loaded to draw portions of it. You would need to maintain some sort of array of indexes to tile positions for your map. Changing tiles for explosion craters or whatnot would be as simply as updating the index in the map array. This concept also works well for sprites where all animation frames go into a single texture so running, walking, attacking, dying, etc only take one texture. Consider also a texture pool so textures only get loaded once and only when needed.

Comment: @Banthar: I already have in mind that, have a tileset in one texture and use glTexCoord to select what tile of the set draw. But even so, I have to execute the block glBegin and glEnd each time that draw a tile, am I right??   @Michael Dorgan:  the textures of the tile's aren't going to change, I will have a texture that store a tileset, so the map itself it's not going to change, it's the vector of tiles that it's going to change, for example instead of draw in the matrix position [1][2] the tile with index 3, in the next iteration in that position will draw the tile with index 4.

Comment: @oscar.rpr: No, you don't. You need a _single_ glBegin/glEnd to draw all your tiles. You can send more than 4 vertices within a begin/end pair. When rendered with `GL_QUADS`, each set of 4 vertices will be seen as a separate quad. Doing this will _dramatically_ improve performance.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: So I could do a loop inside of the block glBegin/glEnd for all my positions, instead of hard-coding the positions of the tiles?  Thanks.

Comment: @oscar.rpr: Yes, that's the idea. I have an answer to a very similar question that goes into more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352235/dynamic-tile-display-optimalization-in-opengl/6352397#6352397

Comment: So I try the method that you propose, but if the perfomance doesn't improve I move to VBO's?.....Thanks

Comment: In the main post I update the method for drawing the tile map, and I tested with only one texture filling all the map and the performance it's almost the same, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @oscar.rpr You should get at least some increase. Are you sure you are not doing something time consuming elsewhere? Try commenting out just gl* draw calls and see how faster it gets.

Comment: @Banthar: Commenting the draw functions in renderApplication, shows the CPU usage at 1%, when I comment only the function for draw the map the CPU usage it's at 2% tops. But when I execute all the draw for the map, goes up to 25%.

Comment: Finally found the problem, apparently was this line: map->getMapTiles() in the drawMap function. Because this function is call in each iteration the profiler of Visual Studio 2010 tells me that consume most of the CPU of my application. So I declare this in the top of drawMap: std::vector<std::vector<TilePtr>> mapT = map->getMapTiles(); and the calls to the function stack goes in this part to minimum. Thanks everyone for the help and I hope someone find this useful.